# jQuery - move div using each inside of click function

Tags: jquery

I want to place the `.move` div is inside of `.destination` when `.gridview` is clicked else inside of `.item` if `.listview` is clicked.

Currently when either view is clicked the `.move` div is iterated multiple times. How do I change the code so that the `.move` div is appended once for each `.item`?

```js
$(".gridview").on("click", function() {
  $(".item").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find(".move").appendTo(".destination");
  });
  var $this = $(this).closest(".container");
  $this.find(".listview").removeClass("active");
  $this.find(".gridview").addClass("active");
  $this.find(".block").css("display", "flex");
});

$(".listview").on("click", function() {
  $(".item").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $list = $this.closest(".list");
    $this.find(".move").appendTo(".item");
  });
  var $this = $(this).closest(".container");
  $this.find(".gridview").removeClass("active");
  $this.find(".listview").addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.item {
  margin: 1.3rem 0;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.destination {
  height: 35px;
  border: 3px solid
}

.move {
  height: 25px;
  border: 2px solid;
  background: green
}

.block {
  display: none;
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.active {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="gridview">Grid</div>
  <div class="listview active">List</div>
  <div class="list">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="destination"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="move"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="destination"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="move"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current code you are using `appendTo(".destination")` this will append all `.move` div inside every `destination` div instead use `appendTo($(this).find(".destination"))` so  this will append only to current items destination div. Same for `listview` you need to use `$(this)` because here you need to append to `item` div itself.

***Demo Code***:

```js
$(".gridview").on("click", function() {
  $(".item").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find(".move").appendTo($(this).find(".destination")); //find destination div inside item and append there 
  });
  var $this = $(this).closest(".container");
  $this.find(".listview").removeClass("active");
  $this.find(".gridview").addClass("active");
  $this.find(".block").css("display", "flex");
});

$(".listview").on("click", function() {
  $(".item").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $list = $this.closest(".list");
    $this.find(".move").appendTo($(this)); //append to current item which is refer currently inside each
  });
  var $this = $(this).closest(".container");
  $this.find(".gridview").removeClass("active");
  $this.find(".listview").addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.item {
  margin: 1.3rem 0;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.destination {
  height: 35px;
  border: 3px solid
}

.move {
  height: 25px;
  border: 2px solid;
  background: green
}

.block {
  display: none;
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.active {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="gridview">Grid</div>
  <div class="listview active">List</div>
  <div class="list">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="destination"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="move"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="destination"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="move"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the below code?

```
$(".gridview").on("click", function() {
  $.each($(".list .item"),function(i,v){ 
   $(this).find(".destination").append($(v).find(".move"))
 })
  var $this = $(this).closest(".container");
  $this.find(".listview").removeClass("active");
  $this.find(".gridview").addClass("active");
  $this.find(".block").css("display", "flex");
});

$(".listview").on("click", function() {
   $.each($(".list .item"),function(i,v){
      $(this).append($(v).find(".destination .move"))
    })
  var $this = $(this).closest(".container");
  $this.find(".gridview").removeClass("active");
  $this.find(".listview").addClass("active");
});
```